# System.Management.ManagementClass.GetInstances() throws exception

Tags: c#, wmi, system.management

On different machines, we see different exceptions.

One machine reports

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (The RPC server is
>   unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA))

Another reports

> System.BadImageFormatException ( An attempt was made to load a program
>   with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B))

Yet another reports

> System.InvalidCastException (Specified cast is not valid.)

What causes this and what's the correct fix?

Comment: the second error you show is probably because of x86 / x64 exe format.

Comment: In machine with first error try to turn off firewall. If it helps then try to add exception to 135 port.

Comment: @DavidePiras my exe is always in x86 format.

Comment: and all machines with x86 os?

Comment: not all client machines are x86 of course. afaik, x86 exe should work on x64 machines.

Comment: I've witnessed the third InvalidCastException in the wild. Internally it seems to be stemming from an internal method System.Management.ManagementScope.InitializeGuts which calls ThrowExceptionForHR on some exceptional condition.